# Why NLog to Azure blob storage doesn't work?

Tags: azure, nlog, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 and want to switch from writing logs to a file to azure blob storage.
and getting no blobs written.

nlog.config (partial for brevity):

```
 <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" />
  </extensions>

 <target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage" name="azure" 
      container="logs" 
      connectionString="**REMOVED**" 
      blobName="test.log" 
      layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}}|${logger:shortName=true}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
```

Internal log:

> Error AzureBlobStorageTarget: Failed to initialize blob=test.log in
>   container=logs Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   NLog.Targets.BlobStorageTarget.CloudBlobService.InitializeContainer(String
>   containerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   NLog.Targets.BlobStorageTarget.CloudBlobService.InitializeAndCacheBlobAsync(String
>   containerName, String blobName, String contentType, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Have tried the *connectionStringKey* alternative with the same results.
I have a *logs* container in the said storage account.

any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/BlobStorageTarget.cs#L342 looks strange. It probably should have been `container` instead of `_container` (that is indeed uninitialized yet)

Comment: Created https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/pull/50 to resolve this. Until then use https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/) Version 2.0.1 has just been released.